# Coverting a TMyQuery dataset to TClientDataSet in Delphi

Tags: delphi, devart, mydac

I make use of the Mydac components by devart   (corelab)  to access MySql from Delphi (2006)
Very often I need to work with data in a TClientDataSet 
What is the best way to convert the dataset of a TMyQuery  to TClientDataSet 
Currently I am using

```
var
    MyQuery : TMyQuery;
    Dsp     : TDataSetProvider;
    Cds     : TClientDataSet;
begin
    MyQuery := nil;
    Dsp     := nil;
    Cds     := nil;
    try
        MyQuery            := TMyQuery.Create(nil);
        Dsp                := TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
        Cds                := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
        MyQuery.Connection := TheConnection;
        MyQuery.SQL.Text   := CmdStr;
        Dsp.DataSet := MyQuery;
        Cds.SetProvider(Dsp);
        Cds.Open;
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///                  MAKE USES OF THE CDS                             //
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    finally
        FreeAndNil(Cds);
        FreeAndNil(Dsp);
        FreeAndNil(MyQuery);
    end;
end;
```

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really do need this very often, then make it a function, like so:

```
function CreateAndOpenClientDataset(AOwner: TComponent;
  AConnection: TConnection; ACommand: string): TClientDataSet;
var
  MyQuery: TMyQuery;
  Dsp: TDataSetProvider;
begin
  Result := TClientDataSet.Create(AOwner);
  try
    MyQuery := TMyQuery.Create(Result);
    MyQuery.Connection := AConnection;
    MyQuery.SQL.Text := ACommand;

    Dsp := TDataSetProvider.Create(Result);
    Dsp.DataSet := MyQuery;

    Result.SetProvider(Dsp);
    Result.Open;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

This function you can use in all places instead of TClientDataSet.Create(), and unless an exception is raised you will be given an open TClientDataSet which owns and that way also frees the two helper objects.

(Note: I only use the DevArt components for MS Sql Server, so I can't test. The code may well contain errors, but the general idea works.)

Comment: +1 for the way you linked the helper objects to the TClientDataSet

Comment: Done. As I have only copied your code from the question, please do edit your question too - it has both MyQuery.Open() and Cds.Open().