# How can I move data from TDataSet to TClientDataSet? I need XML representation of the data

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, tclientdataset, tdataset

How can I easily move data from `TDataSet` to `TClientDataSet`? I need XML representation of the data in `TClientDataSet.XMLData` property.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405065/coverting-a-tmyquery-dataset-to-tclientdataset-in-delphi/405107#405107

Comment: And this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150775/how-to-convert-rows-of-a-database-query-to-a-xml-file/12152426#12152426

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop a `TDataSetProvider` onto the form or datamodule with the ClientDataSet, set the ClientDataSets property `ProviderName` to the name of the `TDataSetProvider`. Set the `DataSet` property of the `TDataSetProvider` to the other dataset. Open the ClientDataSet.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Only fields structure was copied successfully.

Comment: As this is the way it is supposed to work, it might be due to some settings in your setup. You can try to call `ClientDataSet.Last` before getting the XML, just to make sure that all data is actually loaded.

Comment: The first row isn't loaded too. So why the last should be loaded?

Comment: Well, I tried here with the description in my answer and it works perfectly. You should provide more information to track down the problem.

Comment: Uwe, can you show the code? I have used from the second answer. Also I have TDBGrid connected to TDataSet.

Comment: I've marked it as the answer but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Not much code to show. Just dropped a TTable, TClientDataSet, TDataSetProvider, TButton and TMemo onto a form, connected as told above and wrote this code into the ButtonClick:`ClientDataSet1.Open;
Memo1.Lines.Text := ClientDataSet1.XMLData;`

Answer (score 1):

This is from the perspective of a TClientDataset derivative.

```
procedure TMyClientDataset.CopyFromDatasetProvider(Dataset: TDataset);
 var DataSetProvider : TDataSetProvider;
begin
  DataSetProvider := nil;
  try
    Close;
    DataSetProvider := TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
    DatasetProvider.Options := [poNoReset];
    StoreDefs := False;
    DataSetProvider.DataSet := Dataset;
    SetProvider(DataSetProvider);
    Open;
    First;
    SetProvider(nil);
   finally
    if Assigned(DataSetProvider)
     then DataSetProvider.Free;
   end;

end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but why did you use `DatasetProvider.Options := [poNoReset];` and `StoreDefs := False;`?

Comment: This code returns `TMyClientDataset.RecordCount` = 0 with the correct fields structure.

Comment: StoreDefs leaves out Filter Information.  See Online Help.  I actually got this code I found online.  Don't know what to tell you, I use this all the time copy ADODatasets to TClientDatasets.